# Forcing localhost while trying to connect with remote mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, gulp, localhost

I'm trying to fire remote data base with gulp file, so i do this:

```
MYSQL_URL=mysql:url.amazon.com:3306/j2wzwckw00sgx8ul gulp
```

but system is forcing localhost and root user, how to avoid this?